# jqplot render outside visual area

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I'm using jqplot to draw a simple bar chart however only half of the first and last bar are being rendered.
here is the image[image]

Is there a way to make the chart fit inside??

Thanks

**UPDATE**
**On xAxis I'm using dateAxisRenderer as a renderer.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the `axes: { xaxis: { } }` options I would try using the:

```
min: null,      // minimum numerical value of the axis.  Determined automatically.
max: null,      // maximum numverical value of the axis.  Determined automatically.
pad: 1.2,       // a factor multiplied by the data range on the axis to give the
                // axis range so that data points don't fall on the edges of the axis.
```

options.  Bump of the pad first, if that doesn't work, you should try setting min and max values slightly larger than your data range.

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

I think you'll find it much easier to work with dates if you go with the javascript standard of number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.  This is why you get an error using min/max as strings.  Specify it like this:

```
min: 1325376000 * 1000, // 2012/01/01 00:00:00
max: 1326715140 * 1000  // 2012/01/16 11:59:00
```

[Using this min/max](http://jsfiddle.net/N2ker/3/):

[image]

The next hurdle is that your dates do not have times. JQPlot is taking these to be the very first minute of that day, so they line up with the label accordingly.  If you want them to center align you'll need to specify a 12:00pm time.  Again you can parse that from the string, but I would switch over to milliseconds.

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply. That's what I thought... however I'm using dateAxisRenderer and in this case I need to specify the min or it will throw a JS error, also the pad option I think is ignored in this case.

Comment: @DouaBeri, can you set-up a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem?

Comment: http://jsbin.com might work better if there are some conflicts with other scripts/CSS with jsfiddle.

Comment: @Mark http://jsfiddle.net/N2ker/1/  if you comment the  min: "2012-01-01"+""  it will throw you an error